# Can a View be focused and invisible at the same time?

Tags: android, android-edittext

I want to have an `EditText` in focus so it is edited, but also invisible. In other words, all the user will see is the keyboard.

Is that possible?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

AFAIK, an invisibility Edittext cannot have a view( I have never tried) so the workaround for you is

**You can set a transaparent background for edittext to achieve this.**

```
youredittext.setBackgroundResource(android.R.color.transparent);
```

or you can directly set the attribute in XML like this

```
android:background="@null"
```

Answer (score 3):

I know I might be late, but recently I had to face a similar problem.

The solution could also be this one (use in `styles.xml` or in the layout):

```
android:layout_width = 0dp
android:layout_height = 0dp
```

That will also let your `EditText` be still focusable.

Answer (score 1):

My two alternate approaches:

**Approach 1:** Fade it out

```
view.animate().alpha(0.0f).setDuration(0);
```

and fade it in when you want it back

```
view.animate().alpha(1.0f).setDuration(0);
```

Setting duration to 0 ensures it happens instantaneously.

**Approach 2:** Set the view outside the screen

```
LayoutParams params = view.getLayoutParameters();
int offset = -80; // offset from the screen border, choose your own
params.setMargins(0, 0, offset, 0); // left, top, right, bottom
view.setLayoutParams(params);
```

and do

```
params.setMargins(0, 0, 0, 0); // left, top, right, bottom
view.setLayoutParams(params);
```

when you want it back.